# What is the best way to maximize damage on Lissandra?

Tags: league-of-legends

I'm building her with

- Rod of Ages
- Rabadon's Deathcap
- Boots
- Lich Bane
- Deathfire Grasp
- Zhonya's Hourglass

Any other ideas? Is Morellonomicon a good item for her? Or is it better to get her an Archangel's Staff?
I want to spam q and make the maximum damage possible!

Comment: Welcome to Arqade!  Unfortunately, your question is difficult to answer objectively.  Are you looking to maximize damage on Lissandra?  Or something else?

Comment: Note for those answering: add in the reasons *why* you would build her a certain way; that's needed to provide a good answer.

Comment: There is a significant lack of Void Staff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just Q upgrade to max, I would start with Deathcap, deathfire grasp, zhonya's hourglass, magic pen boots, magic pen Percentage staff, and liandra's torment.

Since people at the top comment requested the reasoning was simple all 4 items deal its most maximum on ap therefore you get a bigger bonus with deathcap, magic pen percent shreds over their existing magic resist plus more if they don't have any and amplify your damage, and Liandra's torment is for the magic penetration as well as hp shread for 5% if you are dealing with tanks with hp and magic resist.

Also spamming spells over time would mean that you would need a blue buff to continuously spam spells but I highly doubt you will be mana depleted with this gear type and whoever your opponent is fighting wouldn't die.

Comment: I'd never built `liandry's torment` in  lissandra and it's a good idea! Thanks

Comment: @Mueretee If you find that this post provides you with an adequate answer to your question, remember to 'accept' it by clicking the check mark to the left of the post.

Comment: Trouble is all these items add pure ap, but i see no mana or manaregen items. So if you keep on spamming i'm sure you will run out of mana at one point.

Comment: Well his question was the maximum damage done by Q if he spams Q with this items. Pretty sure mana is irrelevant unless he misses all his shots.

Comment: You could build an archangels if they aren't buying much magic resist. The passive bonus AP will give more than 120 if you make it to 2k max mana which most do.

Answer (score 0):

Aim for chalice early game. It's all the mana you'll ever need to spam all day, her passive will do the rest. Buying more mana item defeats the purpose of her passive. Rod of ages or Tear is overboard. Spend your gold on other stuff that add both AP and tankiness.

Answer (score -1):

Replace Rod of Ages with Athene's Unholy Grail or Morrelonomicon for mana regen (needed early) and cooldown reduction.

Comment: Could you expand a bit more on why is mana regen and cd reduction important compared to the benefit of Rod of Ages ?